# EC2 instances are not able to send emails

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ec2

We have EC2 instances in private subnet and the traffic is routed via the NAT Gateway to reach Internet.
EC2 instances are not able to send emails to relaycloud.xyz.com

All the inbound and outbound traffic is allowed in NSG and NACLs.

Error Message says

"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed connected host has failed to respond."

Security Group and NACL have all the traffic allowed both inbound and outbound.

Comment: Can you ping your relaycloud server from your EC2 instance? If not you may have to put your EC2 instance on an allow-list (f/k/a whitelist) for the relaycloud server.

Answer (score 1):

From [Remove port 25 restriction from your EC2 instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/):

> AWS blocks outbound traffic on port 25 (SMTP) of all EC2 instances and Lambda functions by default. If you want to send outbound traffic on port 25, you can request for this restriction to be removed.

It should work fine if you contact your SMTP server on a different port. Otherwise, you'll need to request for the restriction to be removed.